# I am not able to initialize create-react-app for some strange reason

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

create-reate-app is not initializing even I tried everything which was mentioned to get started in react official documentation.
I tried following commands:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

then I recieved this
**
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
**
then I run:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

but still when I repeat npx create-react-app, I recieved the response which I pasted above in bold.
I also tried

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

I have repeated all of this for more than 3 times but it didn't worked now please tell me what's the problem :(

Comment: was the uninstallation successful?

Comment: Thankyou buddy I've ressolved the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

This issue while tried creating new react app with create-react-app, but related to some random JSON reading issues while installations like.. >= 5.0 || 4.0 ..

But the fix below solves multiple and similar issues.

First of all, make sure you have required or latest version of node installed.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Before using create-react-app make sure you clean npm cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Now, is should be fine to create new react app with

```
npx create-react-app tl-app or npx create-react-app
```

if you want to create current directory as project root.